# WebRTC Video Src Object Not Always Working

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, webrtc

So I am having a slight issue with WebRTC and video streaming. I am setting the stream to a video object like so:

```
let videoElement = document.createElement('video');
video.muted = true;
video.srcObject = event.streams[0];

video.onloadedmetadata = function (e) {
     //Is Never Executed
     var playPromise = video.play();

}
```

The event.streams is from a remote client. It works very well when two clients are in the same network, ie on a router in a home, or they are in the same time town under different networks. But it fails when trying to connect to a client that is across the country and the `onloadedmetadata` is never called.

What could be causing it work with connecting two clients that are near each but fail with distance?

Comment: are you using stun or turn options while creating the peerconnection?

Comment: @Karthik I am use Twilio STUN/TURN implementation at https://www.twilio.com/docs/stun-turn/api